# Exonum blockchain ancoring cost

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, exonum

Question to anyone who's using Exonum's anchoring capabilities https://exonum.com/doc/advanced/bitcoin-anchoring/. What's the cost (in BTC) of running anchoring? How to compute/predict it? For example, for a private network with average load of 100 transactions per second, and 6 node cluster how much will it cost to anchor it to BTC?

Answer (score 1):

An anchoring transaction is a regular Bitcoin transaction. There is a calculator that can provide you with the current recommended fee for making one - https://www.buybitcoinworldwide.com/fee-calculator/
Exonum team suggest that you anchor your private blockchain once in two Bitcoin blocks, i.e. every 20 minutes. Currently for a standard SegWit transaction with two inputs and two outputs the fee constitutes 0,26$